# Call between openfire and asterisk user

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip, openfire

I am totally newbie in openfire and asterisk. 
I want to make call from openfire user to asterisk user.
For that I have installed **openfire 3.9.3** and **asterisk 13.3.2 LTS**. Can anyone please help me what I have to do for next step?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk is pbx while openfire is jabber server

It is compleatly independend soft

You can connect asterisk via jabber to openfire, but not clear why you need that.

Comment: Actually i need asterisk module in openfire, So that i can make call from openfire. As you have said like "connect asterisk via jabber openfire" will it fulfil my requirement?

Comment: openfire is jabber.http://asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/ExternalServices_id286789.html

Comment: After many searching i found this link :- http://gnu-linux.org/xmpp-integration-with-asterisk.html  Can you please tell me if you have any idea about that link. It's really appreciable

Comment: Sorry, it is offtopic here and i not do teaching. You have read docs, test and ask question only if you have real issue. "I not want read doc" is not an issue.